# Django : Check object existance in ManytoManyField

Tags: django, python-2.7, manytomanyfield

I have ChatRoom model as,

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile,related_name='members')
    members_requested = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile,related_name='member_requested')
    members_blocked = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile,related_name='member_blocked')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

For example I have added a UserProfile instances to members field.

```
chr_obj.members.add(up_obj1,up_obj2)
```

How can i check whether a UserProfile object is there or not. I tried with, 
if `chr_obj.name ='new room'`

up_obj.chatroom_set.filter(name='new room').exists()

but it returns false. How to verify that ?? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your issue may be from the typo?

```
up_obj1.chatroom_set.filter(name='new room').exists()
```

To check, you could run:

```
chr_obj.members.all()
```

Comment: yeah that listing is working. but exists() is not working.. 
So i am handling this issue as up_obj in chr_obj.members.all() .I know this is not efficient but for now i am using this.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using `up_obj1` in the `.exists()` call right?

Comment: yes, m using up_obj which is a UserProfile instance, which having many to many relation to ChatRoom class.

Comment: Hm, if you're sure the user object in `up_obj` exists in members, it SHOULD work. Maybe post the whole view or function you're using?